# l3: splitting and randomizing a token list

Tags: latex3

I am trying to grasp the ins and out of LaTeX3. I want to do the following:
I have defined a environment `randomizechoices` with `NewDoucmentEnvironment` that grabs the contents. This contents is then parsed. When parsing, I want to split a token list on a token (to a sequence), then randomize the sequence and then build back the token list. This token list is then typeset. Now randomizing a token list is not directly available, but randomizing a sequence is. So I need to convert the token list to a (split) sequence, randomize it and build back the token list (or any way to do it). A MWE is shown below:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% for now
\NewDocumentCommand{\inaccessible}{}{X}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{randomizechoices}{ +!b }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl {#1}
   
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_my_tl {\CorrectChoice} {\choice \inaccessible}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_my_tl {\correctchoice} {\choice \inaccessible}

    % shuffle on \choice in token list
    
    % - or -
    
    % Convert to sequence on \choice, shuffle, rebuild
    
    % - or -
    
    % Convert to string, split on \choice to sequence, shuffle, rebuild
    
    %
  \begin{choices}
  \tl_use:N \l_my_tl
  \end{choices}
  }
  {}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question
Blah
\begin{randomizechoices}
\choice Hello
\choice World!
\CorrectChoice and
\choice everyone!
\end{randomizechoices}

\question
Blah
\begin{randomizechoices}
\choice Hello
\choice World!
\correctchoice and
\choice everyone!
\end{randomizechoices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following does this by using a sequence.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% for now
\NewDocumentCommand{\inaccessible}{}{X}

% initialize the used variables
\tl_new:N \l_my_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l_my_body_seq
\NewDocumentEnvironment{randomizechoices}{ +!b }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_my_body_tl {#1}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_my_body_tl {\CorrectChoice} {\choice \inaccessible}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_my_body_tl {\correctchoice} {\choice \inaccessible}
    % set sequence split at \choice
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_my_body_seq { \choice } \l_my_body_tl
    % remove empty elements
    \seq_remove_all:Nn \l_my_body_seq {}
    \seq_shuffle:N \l_my_body_seq
    % put back randomized sequence with \choice between the items
    \tl_set:Nx \l_my_body_tl
      {
        \exp_not:N \choice
        \seq_use:Nn \l_my_body_seq \choice
      }
  \begin{choices}
    \tl_use:N \l_my_body_tl
  \end{choices}
  }
  {}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question
Blah
\begin{randomizechoices}
\choice Hello
\choice World!
\CorrectChoice and
\choice everyone!
\end{randomizechoices}

\question
Blah
\begin{randomizechoices}
\choice Hello
\choice World!
\correctchoice and
\choice everyone!
\end{randomizechoices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**This builds on [@egreg's fantastic answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/609223/117050)** but changes some simple aspects of it:

- I changed the marker to be a quark
- I changed the test for said marker to be fully expandable, this way the sequence used as output does only contain the contents once instead of thrice (imho, cleaner code)
- add the possibility to place a label (only makes sense if you set the seed of `expl3` to a fixed value)

```
\documentclass{exam}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\sys_gset_rand_seed:n { \fp_eval:n { round(1e6 * pi) } }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{randomizechoices}{ o +b }
  { \jodb_choices_randomize:nn {#1} {#2} }
  {}

% initialize the used variables
\tl_new:N \l_jodb_choices_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l_jodb_choices_body_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l_jodb_choices_body_out_seq

\quark_new:N \q__jodb_choices_marker

\cs_set_protected:Npn \jodb_choices_randomize:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_jodb_choices_body_tl {#2}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_jodb_choices_body_tl
      {\CorrectChoice} {\choice \q__jodb_choices_marker}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_jodb_choices_body_tl
      {\correctchoice} {\choice \q__jodb_choices_marker}
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_jodb_choices_body_in_seq
      { \choice } \l_jodb_choices_body_tl
    % first item is empty
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l_jodb_choices_body_in_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    % randomize
    \seq_shuffle:N \l_jodb_choices_body_in_seq
    % build another sequence
    \seq_set_map_x:NNn \l_jodb_choices_body_out_seq \l_jodb_choices_body_in_seq
      {
        \tl_if_head_eq_meaning:nNTF { ##1 } \q__jodb_choices_marker
          {
            \exp_not:n { \CorrectChoice }
            \IfValueT {#1} { \exp_not:n { \label{#1} } }
            \exp_not:o { \use_none:n ##1 }
          }
          { \exp_not:n { \choice ##1 } }
      }
    \begin{choices}
      \seq_use:Nn \l_jodb_choices_body_out_seq {  }
    \end{choices}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printanswers

\begin{questions}

\question
Blah
\begin{randomizechoices}[ans:blah]
\choice Hello
\choice World!
\CorrectChoice and
\choice everyone!
\end{randomizechoices}

\question
Blah (but see also \ref{ans:blah})
\begin{randomizechoices}
\choice Hello
\choice World!
\correctchoice and
\choice everyone!
\end{randomizechoices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was seaching for the V in `\seq_set_split:NnV \l_my_body_seq { \choice } \l_my_body_tl`

Comment: why is `\use_i:nn` needed?

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw to remove the `\q__jodb_choices_marker` which is at the start of `##1` (if you omit this you'll get an infinite loop, as a quark expands to itself).

Comment: Yes, I found out the hard way ;-)

Comment: So `{ \exp_not:n { \CorrectChoice \use_ii:nn ##1 } }` would also do the trick?

Comment: I want to add a label based on a boolean, like `          { \exp_not:n { \CorrectChoice \bool_if:NTF \l_label_bool { \label{question@\thequestion@correctchoice} } {} \use_ii:nn ##1 } }` but I am keeping errors.

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw I've added some code to place a label using an optional argument. Also, you should use `\use_none:n` to only remove the first element of a token list, not use `\use_ii:nn` as that could have unwanted side effects by stripping a group (just imagine you did `\CorrectChoice {\color{blue} Something in blue}`.

Comment: Yes! THANK YOU! Now I have `{ \exp_not:n { \CorrectChoice } \bool_if:NTF \l_label_bool { \exp_not:n { \label{question@\thequestion @correctchoice} } } { } \exp_not:o { \use_none:n ##1 } }
          { \exp_not:n { \choice ##1 } }`

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw I'd argue against using the `\thequestion` counter inside the label and for the explicit optional argument to set a *speaking* name. The entire idea behind the labels is to give speaking informative names instead of numeric information which might change.

Comment: Yes, but I need the label to be in place with the question, so the easiest way is to use `\thequestion`.

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw in that case, use `\value{question}` instead of `\thequestion` (the latter might contain formatting, the former expands to the value of the counter and should be used for programmatically accessing the value of a counter, `\thequestion` is only meant for output in the document).

Comment: I think you meant `\arabic{question}`.

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw no, `\value` is correct. Though you'd have to use `\the\value{question}` here (`\value` would be enough for things like `\ifnum`). Sorry for omitting the `\the`.

Answer (score 6):

The key is `\seq_set_split:NnV`, so the sequence is populated with the items separated by `\choice` and it can be randomized.

Then you can rebuild the sequence by reinserting `\choice` or `\CorrectChoice` (in case the marker is present in the item).

```
\documentclass{exam}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{randomizechoices}{ +b }
  {
    \jodb_choices_randomize:n { #1 }
  }
  {}

% initialize the used variables
\tl_new:N \l_jodb_choices_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l_jodb_choices_body_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l_jodb_choices_body_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jodb_choices_marker: { }

\cs_set_protected:Nn \jodb_choices_randomize:n
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_jodb_choices_body_tl {#1}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_jodb_choices_body_tl {\CorrectChoice} {\choice \__jodb_choices_marker:}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_jodb_choices_body_tl {\correctchoice} {\choice \__jodb_choices_marker:}
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_jodb_choices_body_in_seq { \choice } \l_jodb_choices_body_tl
    % first item is empty
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l_jodb_choices_body_in_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    % randomize
    \seq_shuffle:N \l_jodb_choices_body_in_seq
    % build another sequence
    \seq_set_map_x:NNn \l_jodb_choices_body_out_seq \l_jodb_choices_body_in_seq
      {
        \tl_if_in:nnTF { ##1 } { \__jodb_choices_marker: }
          { \exp_not:n { \CorrectChoice ##1 } }
          { \exp_not:n { \choice ##1 } }
      }
    \begin{choices}
    \seq_use:Nn \l_jodb_choices_body_out_seq {  }
    \end{choices}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printanswers

\begin{questions}

\question
Blah
\begin{randomizechoices}
\choice Hello
\choice World!
\CorrectChoice and
\choice everyone!
\end{randomizechoices}

\question
Blah
\begin{randomizechoices}
\choice Hello
\choice World!
\correctchoice and
\choice everyone!
\end{randomizechoices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Sorry, but adding a label to the correct choice is not going to work, because at each LaTeX run references will typically change.

[image]

Comment: Nice! I want the `\inaccessible` token as a marker in the sequence, so I can rebuild the randomized sequence with `\choice` or `\CorrectChoice` to a token list. And also apply a `\label` to the correct choice

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw Reimplemented according to your remark.

Comment: This is really nice. I did applying a label in the LaTeX2 package `exam-randomizechoices` (using `\patchcmd`) and it worked for me. If the randomizer seed is constant, the place of `\CorrectChoice` would be the same every run. Then a label could be applied, or not?

Comment: I really should have voted this answer as the best, but cannot change it. Hitting the button to fast.

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw Don't worry. Skillmon gave the right idea.

Comment: The usage of `\seq_set_map_x:NNn` seems wrong here, imho, as `\tl_if_in:nnTF` isn't expandable (I know that it works here, but it seems wrong to me, effectively tripling the contents of the `seq`). Also, I'd say that `\__jodb_choices_marker:` should be `\scan_new:N \s__jodb_choices_marker` instead. But great answer nonetheless!

Comment: @Skillmon Indeed I found that the sequence is full of `\tl_if_in:nnTF`, but it typesets correctly. I would like to expand the `\tl_if_in:nnTF`, so the sequence is not clobbered. Could you shed a light on how to circumvent this?

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw I've made an edit to my answer including the necessary changes. `\tl_if_in:nnTF` can't be expanded, it works by assignments.

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw also, I think now that I made an edit to my answer you can untick it and award the tick to this answer.